# Sms intent not working in sony xperia

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sending an mms from my application. Its working correctly in all devices but when i am using sony xperia, its neither adding recipients nor the sms body.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
intent.putExtra("address", "9412121212");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
intent.putExtra("sms_body","hii");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);                                         
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");          
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, final_sms_txt);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
Should i include my package name here ?

Comment: http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2014/01/custom-chooser-android-in-example.html refer this link.